# Why max size of response body send from express only limit at 36544b?

Tags: express, ubuntu, nginx

i am using expressjs to create an app. I hosted it on an ubuntu vps and used nginx as a proxy reverse.

But the body of response only limit at 36544b.
I ran it in a windows computer but it doesn't have any limit!

I use both source code. 630404 is the size of image i send as buffer. But when i send it in ubuntu vps it reduce to 36544. The image i have from response only have a litle bit data on top

I tried send another type of the body like json but it only limit at 36544b. However, i add 100kb string to an json key but it reduce to fit 36544b.

I think the error from expressjs.

My nginx config:
[image: nginx config]

Windows:
[image: Windows]

Ubuntu:
[image: Ubuntu]

Comment: Is 36544 bytes perhaps the size of the compressed response which contains 630404 bytes when uncompressed?

Comment: No. I use both source code. 630404 is the size of image i send as buffer. But when i send it in ubuntu vps it reduce to 36544. The image i have from response only have a litle bit data on top